# Not saving texts when selecting other option from dropdown list in HTML form

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am using the following code to develop a dropdown list in a html form.

```
<html:select property="complaintCategory" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" >
<html:option value="option1">option1</html:option>
<html:option value="option2">option2</html:option>
<html:option value="option3">option3</html:option>
<html:option value="Other">Other</html:option>
</html:select>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

I want to create a text box so that user can write something when they select **Other** option. The function showField(name) is creating the new text box.

```
function showfield(name)
    {
        if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<input type="text" name="complaintCategory" />';
        else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
    }
```

The problem I am facing is that when I select "Other" option from the dropdown list and then write something on it, it is not saving the texts, it is saved as value **Other** only. I want to pass the texts written in the text box as the complaintCategory. Would really appreciate someone's help on this, i am stuck.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

(I'm working on the assumption that `<html:select property="complaintCategory"` will output `<select name="complaintCategory"`. It is usually helpful to narrow down the problem to server side code or client side code and provide only one of them.)

When you submit the form (after selecting other) you will have *2* elements with the same name.

Whatever server side code you are using to read the submitted form data, it appears to be taking the *first* value.

Either:

1. Modify your server side code to get the second value (I don't know the API you are using to parse the form data so I can't tell you the specifics for that)
2. Call the generated input by a different name and an if statement.

e.g.

client side:

```
if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<input type="text" name="otherComplaintCategory" />';
```

server side (psuedo code):

```
IF complaintCategory is "Other":
THEN complaintCategory = otherComplaintCategory
```